# Researching Music

Tags: theory, learning

I have recently started researching music in the area of music and learning instruments. While my university has given me access to a number of resources such as JSTOR and EBSCO in addition to their own database, I am surprisingly having a difficult time finding sufficient peer-reviewed articles for my topic. How can I find more scholarly sources?

Comment: Welcome! Requests for specific resources, like "what is a good website for ___," are not one of the [topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). But I encourage you to edit your question into something broader and more practical like "How do I start collecting materials when researching a musical topic?", which allows some hows and whys besides the wheres.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musicology lists some perspectives and topics for music research, and if you follow the links, you will probably find examples of existing research. Look at what they have used as material.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I've put back in a lot of your original wording, since your problem might have more to do with your topic than with the databases, journals, or sources.

Comment: The short answer is: 1) if there's nothing written about your topic, then either you have to conduct your own original ground-breaking research in that field, or shift your topic. 2) Good sources cite other sources. Follow the "paper trail" and check out the sources' sources. 3) Cast a broad net at first. If my topic is Ravel's violin piece *Tzigane*, I check the indexes of Ravel biographies or books on impressionist music for mention of it. In this early stage, start with "secondary sources" like Grove Music Online, and then move on to the sources they cite.

Comment: Also, scholar.google.com can be helpful at tracking citations, books.google.com can be better than an index (and can give you quick access to public-domain primary sources), and your local librarian can help you use Interlibrary Loan to access items in other libraries.